# Is there a solution to separating number and operators of a string?

Tags: python

I want separate numbers and operator signs from a string.

**Example:**

input - `"12+34=46"`
output - `12, +, 34, 46`

**Code Used:**

```
def seperator(runes):
    runes = list(runes)
    operators = ["-", "+", "/", "*"]
    
    index1 = 0
    index2 = 0
    for i in range(len(runes)):
        cond1 = runes[i-1] >"-1" and runes[i-1] < "10"
        cond2 = runes[i-1] == "?"
        if runes[i] in operators and (cond1 or cond2):
            index1 = i
        if runes[i] == "=":
            index2 = i

    num1 = runes[:index1]
    operator = runes[index1]
    num2 = runes[index1+1: index2]
    output = runes[index2+1:len(runes)]

    return num1,  operator, num2, output
```

**Inputs**

```
print(seperator("1+1=2"))
print(seperator("123*456=56088"))
print(seperator("-58*-1=50"))
```

**Results**

1. `('1', '+', '1', '2')`
2. `('', '1', '23*456', '56088')`
3. `('-50', '*', '-1', '50')`

**Problem**

I was wondering why I am getting the wrong output for the 2nd result.

I tried to remove the conditions cond1 and cond2 which seems to work for 2nd result but fail for others.

Comment: `runes[i-1] >"-1" and runes[i-1] < "10"` doesn't work because strings don't compare the same way as their numeric values.

Comment: If this is always of the form "number operator number equals number" you should consider writing a regular expression and capture the groups.

Comment: Plus, when i=0, ``runes[i-1]`` is ``runes[-1]``. Which does not crash in python as it would in C. Because that means "last element of runes". But I am pretty sure it is not the wanted behaviour

Comment: Does `re.findall(r"[0-9]+|[\+\-\*/]", "12+34=46")` works for you?

Comment: @jvx8ss there is still a problem with negative numbers

Comment: @jvx8ss My answer below uses a similar regex but works with negatives. Although I used `re.search` instead of `re.findall`.

Comment: Yes. what about `r"-?[0-9]+|[\+\-\*/]"` ?

Comment: @jvx8ss Then it doesn't work with subtraction of positive numbers. Like ``1-2=-1``

Comment: It is not an easy problem, and I doubt there can be a one-liner. Unless, as Michael did, you assume that the "syntax" is known and fixed (operand operator operand equal operand).

Comment: Well, when I say, "I doubt there can be a one-liner", I meant, an obvious one. I have seen so many seemingly impossible working one-liner on SO in python, that I wouldn't be sure of anything. Reason why I am still stalking this question :D

Comment: But, well, it is a classical lexicography/syntax problem. And one-liners usually just deal with lexicographic one. Expression parsers, in most language, would parse only positive numbers (I mean unsigned. It would be the same with unary +) at lexicographic level. Then would, at syntax level, discriminate between binary - and unary -.

Comment: My feeling is that this is (without using lex and bison, of course, since it is a way simpler problem than parsing a whole language) what should also be done here. Using something like your first regex for lexicography. Extracting bunch of operators, and numbers. Then, in a 2nd (syntaxic, somehow) pass, decide which - and + should be considered unary operators, and merged with the following numbers. Criterium is easy: those are the '-' and '+' that do not follow another operator)

Comment: Michael's answer works in his choice of restricted syntax, because there isn't a need for a syntax parsing if syntax is completely static. But otherwise

Comment: If your input is basically valid Python, you might want to look at the `tokenize` module in the standard library. The output won't be a simple list of strings, but it shouldn't be too difficult to recover the original strings from the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is a regex. Here's what I came up with:

```
import re


def seperator(runes):
    match = re.search('(-?[0-9]+)([+\-*\/])(-?[0-9]+)(=)(-?[0-9]+)', runes.replace(' ', ''))
    return match.groups()


print(seperator("1+1=2"))  # => ('1', '+', '1', '=', '2')
print(seperator("123*456=56088"))  # => ('123', '*', '456', '=', '56088')
print(seperator("-58*-1=50"))  # => ('-58', '*', '-1', '=', '50')
```

The regex here is `(-?[0-9]+)([+\-*\/])(-?[0-9]+)(=)(-?[0-9]+)`. Note that each `(-?[0-9]+)` represents a number and `([+\-*\/])` represents the operator.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses a loop instead of any inbuilt function and passes all the test cases mentioned.

```
def seperator(my_string):
    my_string = "".join(my_string.split(" "))
    res = []
    number_stack = []
    for i in range(0, len(my_string)):
        char = my_string[i]
        if char in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]:
            number_stack.append(char)
        else:
            if char == "-":
                if i == 0:
                    number_stack.append(char)
                else:
                    if my_string[i-1] in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]:
                        res.append(''.join(number_stack))
                        number_stack = []
                        res.append(char)
                    else:
                        number_stack.append(char)
            else:
                res.append(''.join(number_stack))
                number_stack = []
                res.append(char)
    res.append(''.join(number_stack))
    return res

print(seperator("1+1=2"))  # ['1', '+', '1', '=', '2']
print(seperator("123*456=56088"))  # ['123', '*', '456', '=', '56088']
print(seperator("-58*-1=50"))  # ['-58', '*', '-1', '=', '50']
print(seperator("10-10=0"))  # ['10', '-', '10', '=', '0']
print(seperator("10--10=0"))  # ['10', '-', '-10', '=', '0']
print(seperator("1 + 1 = 2"))  # ['1', '+', '1', '=', '2']
```